# SSIS Package execution succeed but no mail sent

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have crated SSIS project which does the following thing

Control Flow :-

[image]

Data Flow:-

[image]

- It first delete data in excel sheet
- Create new excel sheet
- insert data from database to excel file
- Send mail of that excel file

When i execute it by right click on package and say execute it works well(mail sent). But when i schedule the package in Sql Server Agent job to run it shows me "Package execution succeed" but no mail is sent. though it is able to insert data into excel sheet.

**Then Why Mail is not being sent by SQL Server Agent Job ?**

SQL Job Runs in SQL Service Account so i given "Full Access" permission to my excel file for SQL Server Job Agent User.

**No Error[With Warnings] As per SQL Agent Job But No Mail Being Sent**

```
The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0) but had warnings, with warnings being treated as errors.  Started:  4:16:51 PM  Finished: 4:17:04 PM  Elapsed:  13.119 seconds.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.
```

Email Script Code:-

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ST_cb3e2bf527bb45c58359315bb058656e.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion    

        public void Main()
        {
            string sSubject = "Monitum : ICICI Cash Balance : "+DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()+" : "+DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
            string sBody = "";
            int iPriority = 2;

            if (SendMail(sSubject, sBody, iPriority))
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                //Fails the Task
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }

        public bool SendMail(string sSubject, string sMessage, int iPriority)
        {
            try
            {
                string sEmailServer = Dts.Variables["User::sEmailServer"].Value.ToString();                
                string sEmailPort = Dts.Variables["User::sEmailPort"].Value.ToString();                
                string sEmailUser = Dts.Variables["User::sEmailUser"].Value.ToString();                
                string sEmailPassword = Dts.Variables["User::sEmailPassword"].Value.ToString();                
                string sEmailSendTo = Dts.Variables["User::sEmailSendTo"].Value.ToString();                
                string sEmailSendFrom = Dts.Variables["User::sEmailSendFrom"].Value.ToString();                
                string sEmailSendFromName = Dts.Variables["User::sEmailSendFromName"].Value.ToString();                

                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                Attachment attach = new Attachment("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\ICICI Cash Balance.xls");
                attach.Name = "ICICI_Cash_Balance_"+DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()+"_"+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()+".xls";
                message.Attachments.Add(attach);
                MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(sEmailSendFrom, sEmailSendFromName);
                message.Bcc.Add("sagar.dumbre@agsindia.com");
                //You can have multiple emails separated by ;
                string[] sEmailTo = Regex.Split(sEmailSendTo, ";");
                //string[] sEmailCC = Regex.Split(sEmailSendCC, ";");
                int sEmailServerSMTP = int.Parse(sEmailPort);

                smtpClient.Host = sEmailServer;
                smtpClient.Port = sEmailServerSMTP;

                System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredentials =
                   new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sEmailUser, sEmailPassword);
                smtpClient.Credentials = myCredentials;

                message.From = fromAddress;

                if (sEmailTo != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sEmailTo.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        if (sEmailTo[i] != null && sEmailTo[i] != "")
                        {
                            message.To.Add(sEmailTo[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                switch (iPriority)
                {
                    case 1:
                        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        message.Priority = MailPriority.Low;
                        break;
                    default:
                        message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                        break;
                }

                message.Subject = sSubject;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Body = sMessage;

                smtpClient.Send(message);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script Task Example", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is sending mail? The script task? If so, post the code.

Comment: I think you'll have to add a custom handler to catch email errors. See the example at the bottom of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx on how MS recommends catching smtpClient errors. Also, use the Log Provider and Dts.Events.FireError method in script task error catching. A messagebox.show doesn't leave much to research after you automate the job in the agent.

Comment: Where to insert "Log Provider and Dts.Events.FireError method" in Script Task ?

Comment: @brian I have modified my Catch block but no error is getting catched. Where to check it though ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm feeling lucky so I'll post without all the details.

My top N reasons it's not working

1. The SQL Server Agent **account** is not allowed to talk to Exchange. Domain\SqlServiceAccount is not a user in Exchange and therefore unable to send mail. Domain\SagarDumbre *is* a user in Exchange and can send mail which is why it works for you.
2. The **server** is not authorized to talk to the Exchange. Your Exchange admin has the ability to authorize IP addresses and even though the account that runs SQL Server can talk to Exchange, the address 192.168.1.101 is not allowed to talk to the mail server. We got bit by this during and Exchange upgrade/maintenance. The admins turned on the feature to prevent spam from being sent from non-authorized addresses and servers weren't on the list.
3. Firewall and/or virus scanner. Since you didn't specify whether the successful send of email works from your machine or the server in question, I have also seen these products block access to a mail server since the requests weren't coming from Outlook.
4. Bad code. Something in your mail sending code is failing or it is receiving an error message from the MTA saying it couldn't handle your request and the code isn't listening or who knows what. Fire off some Information events so you can get feedback from the Script Task.

Talk to your Exchange admin and see if they have details in their log of what is happening. They might want to watch their interface as the package fires to capture the appropriate event.

Comment: Sir, I executed my package on Server itself it works well . mail is being sent but when i configure package (.dtsx) in sql server job then only mail sent fails, all the remaining three steps succeed.

Comment: Antivirus was our source of troubles from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this:

> Sir, I executed my package on Server itself it works well . mail is
>   being sent but when i configure package (.dtsx) in sql server job then
>   only mail sent fails, all the remaining three steps succeed.

I can't comment at this time because StackOverflow doesn't allow me, so don't take this as an answer, so much as a verification based on your comment above this.  Have you configured the values when you select SSIS package to match how you're running on your server?  I run into trouble when I move from the server to the job agent if I don't configure it exactly as is (especially, when I use a config file or set the connection strings differently).  Note that the trouble here *will still run the package with no error, yet not do what it's supposed to do*.

Outside of the above paragraph, your code and steps look good and if it were bad, your package would be breaking on the server itself; so that eliminates some of the possible issues.

Comment: your statement clicked me one thing..Do we have to set up variables in SQL Job also ? coz i already configured it in SSIS package.

Comment: You shouldn't have to, but then again, this depends on how IS and SQLServer are set up.  Your environment may differ than others.  When doing the job look through these tabs and experiment with them: General, Configurations, Command Files, Data Sources, Execution Options, Logging, Set Values, Verification, Command Line.

As an example, sometimes trying to run a package through the server versus file system completely changes what Execution options I need to select.  If the package runs fine on the server itself, the disconnect seems to be here not with the code.

Comment: I hard coded all my variables in code still no mail sent. My problem is Package returns Success even if mail not sent hence no error generate and i cant able to debug it

Answer (score 3):

Your script refers to a path for the attachment that starts C:\Users\Administrator.  I suspect the account used to run the SQL Server Agent service does not have access to that folder.

You can solve this by moving those files to a non-user directory, and ensuring that the account used to run the SQL Server Agent service has access to that directory.

You should also ensure that the account used to run the SQL Server Agent service is allowed to use your SMTP service.

You might also consider using the SSIS Send Mail Task for this - you will avoid a lot of code.

Comment: 1. My SQL Server Agnet Job runs in Administrator account so it has access to excel file. 2. I have tried Send Mail task also..Same problem occurs not able to send mail when run in agent job

Comment: If i able to execute SSIS package manually using DTEXECUI then why not using Agent Job ? both account run on Administrator account

Comment: Log on the SQL Server server using the service account under which your SQL Server service is running. From the command prompt use `dtexec` command to execute your package. Use the `/REPORT V` switch to enable verbose output. Watch the antivirus (if installed). This might give you some additional insight.

Comment: I have changed the setting of SSIS Package. Now it will fail when Warning Occurs. i m getting warning as "The command line parameters are invalid". Step failed. Check question edit