# Spring Batch execution every night (BD SQL-Server)

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, spring-batch, batch-processing

Hi i am trying to create a Batch process but it is the first time that I do something like this and I have many doubts about it,
I need to query two columns of type date in my BD, "DATE_INSERCION" and "DATE_MODIFICACION" and if there are changes (ie one or more greater than the current date) then return the row(s) that have changed.

Now the batch process must be executed every night (for example at one in the morning) and consult the changes, I am working with Maven, it is a functionality to add in the project, I have already studied the theory but I still confuse where to place what And how to call one thing or another of what I need, and what is on the internet is reading files but not real BD,
Some example or guide would be very useful, my idea is to use Spring-batch.

I appreciate the time you take to explain.

When it finishes if there are changes I have to send an email that notifies to certain emails the changes (this structure I have already created), then what I need is to know how to create the batch and where to put the call to the method of "Send mail" with the parameters .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a SQL server agent job, and make you query and email in a SQL package.  Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933803/ssis-package-execution-succeed-but-no-mail-sent

Comment: I've got the batch process working, but I do not know how to make it run every day at one for example, how could I do that?                          
Currently I have a main method in the launcher that I run manually, but how to automate it?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL server:

1. Click to expand on SQL Server Agent, and right click on "Jobs", and pick "New Job..."
2. In the General tab, enter the name of the job and an description.
3. Then on the steps, add a new step, with the step name, and enter EXEC spXXXXXX which would be the name of your stored procedure.
4. Click on Schedules, and click on New, enter a name, and configure the date and times that you want it to run.
5. Press OK, and the new job should be created.